# default selection option blank; implementing

Tags: javascript, html

I am planning on using this code:

**html**:

```
 <select id="myDropdown">      
     <option>Option 1</option>     
     <option>Option 2</option>     
     <option>Option 3</option>     
 </select>
```

and the **javascript**:

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").selectedIndex = -1;
```

but I don't know how to implement this into my page.
This is how I currently have it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myDropdown").selectedIndex = -1;
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="myDropdown">      
    <option>Option 1</option>     
    <option>Option 2</option>     
    <option>Option 3</option>     
    </select> 
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make it so that there is a blank selection when they go on the page but they don't see an empty option. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Try moving the javascript to the body of the page

Comment: @Colum I just tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Bert, to the end of the `<body>`, see my answer below.

Comment: @Colum You were right as-well but I just had to make it at the end of the body, not in the beginning.

Comment: you could also have wrapped the code in `window.onload = function() { [your code here] }` and left it in the head. better yet, get jquery and wrap in `$(document).ready(function() { [your code] })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is in the `<head>`,  it fires before the DOM is ready, move it to the bottom of the `<body>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select id="myDropdown">      
            <option>Option 1</option>     
            <option>Option 2</option>     
            <option>Option 3</option>     
        </select> 
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").selectedIndex = -1;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AZsXj/)